# Robot Inventor Bluetooth not working

Tags: programming, bluetooth, robotic, robot-inventor

A while ago, I started up the Robot Inventor program and noticed the computer was not connecting. When I clicked the "Connect" button, the loading "circle" simply started spinning either indefinitely or for a few seconds until the "Connect" button showed up again. The Bluetooth on my Dell E5540 is on, and the 2 devices are paired.

Comment: Did you try pairing the hub using the Windows Bluetooth settings first?

Comment: @DavidLechner Yep.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this project [legoBTLE4pi](https://github.com/DietrichChristopeit/legoBTLE4PI) could help you.
It connects a Raspberry PI via Bluetooth to a Lego Powered Up Brick and does all the funny stuff.

The project is ongoing (nice TUI etc) but everything works.

Comment: I'm not sure how a Raspberry Pi-based project could help the problem OP is facing with their computer - could you please elaborate on this aspect?

Comment: I thought maybe by using a vm with Linux this problem could be circumvented. However, you're absolutely right, I answered quicker than I thought. Please excuse this lapse.